# Autosuggest using Algolia and FASTAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, swagger-ui, algolia, autosuggest

I am writing a code to implement an autosuggest API using Algolia API. I am new to API creation as well as Algolia. The following code is created using FASTAPI and testing is being done on Swagger UI.
Here is my code below:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import pydantic
from uvicorn import run

from algoliasearch.search_client import SearchClient

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/autosuggest")
async def autosuggest(q: str):
    # Create an Algolia client
    client = SearchClient.create("Algolia_App_ID", "Algolia_API_KEY")

    results = client.search_dictionary_entries(
        q,
        index="Algolia_Index_Name",
        facets=["QuestionText"],
    )

    return results["facets"]["QuestionText"]

    await run(app)
```

I have a CSV file with question and answer in it. The user when inputs a question, the code should start auto-suggesting questions to the user. This CSV file I have already uploaded on Algolia Free trial version browser.

I have been trying for a while. I am getting internal server error on Swagger UI and the terminal says:

```
    results = client.search_dictionary_entries(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: SearchClient.search_dictionary_entries() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index'
```

I went through the documentation, but in no vain. If anyone can guide or correct this code, it would be really helpful.

I read the documentation:

1. https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/methods/search/
2. https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-python/blob/master/algoliasearch/search_client.py
3. https://www.algolia.com/doc/ui-libraries/autocomplete/api-reference/autocomplete-js/getAlgoliaResults/#param-searchclient
4. https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/getting-started/install/python/?client=python#test-your-installation

I did not quite understand the documentation so any help is most welcome.

Comment: The [`search_dictionary_entries()`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/search-dictionary-entries/) method does not seem to have a parameter named `index`.